# How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#

I have used this site https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/828736/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-native-visual-c-code-in-visual-studio-n

Problem-

I have create MyInterop.tlb file and include in Project. 
I have create window installer set up when i install set up on different machine

```
 CoInitialize(NULL); 
IWindowPtr pDotNetCOMPtr;

HRESULT hRes = 
    pDotNetCOMPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(WindowClass));

flag=pDotNetCOMPtr->show ();

CoUninitialize();
```

Class Not registered  issue is occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Com Object needs to be registered. You can do this by checking "Register for COM interop" in the Visual Studio Project as shown in the image or you must register it in your installer run. Make sure you have the headers like the example link you sent

```
RegAsm.exe ManagedDLL.dll /tlb:ManagedDLL.tlb /codebase
```

The COM Object should have a GUID also. This allows the registry to deal with it correctly.

In previous work this these are the headers I included. Each Guid is different for each Object that is being registered.:

```
   [ComVisible(true)]
   [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
   [Guid("7F2DA4BD-12BF-4EE7-80E7-F85D1F15926C")]
```

[image: Register For COM Interop]